# How to properly set pool_size (and max_overflow) in SQLAlchemy for ASGI app

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, asgi

We're building an ASGI app using fastapi, uvicorn, sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL. The question is: how should we set `pool_size` in `create_async_engine` to not make it a bottleneck comparing to a WSGI app with multiple workers?

As far as I understand, in a WSGI app if we run `N` processes with `M` threads each (and `pool_size=M`) we'll get at most `N * M` connections. But what about ASGI (if we have a single process) - how many connections can be opened? Also `pool_size` (since we create only one `AsyncEngine` per process)? Then we should set it as `pool_size=N * M`?

And, if we simply increase this number, than we'll be able to make more simultaneous `await`able requests to the database, right?

What is the intuition behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

in sqlalchemy to add pool size and max overflow u can use

```
engine = create_async_engine(
    settings.ASYNC_SQLALCHEMY_URL,
    echo=settings.SQLALCHEMY_ECHO,
    pool_size=20,
    max_overflow=10,
)
```

In sqlalchemy you dont have max pool size but recommend pool size is 20

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, we're aware about these settings, however, the question is - how does `async` functionality affects tuning process of these parameters? What happens if we issue more `await`able connections than the `pool_size`? Will they get into a queue? And what queue?